# Double quotes("xxx") changes to two double quotes (""xxx"") unexpectedly while read string from file using Python

Tags: python, string, quotes, decode

Here is a problem that has been bothering me a lot about Python, I could really use some help on this:

I'm trying to read some string from a file. The files are .rc suffix where one kind of localized strings are inside for each file. Based on different languages, I used different codepage to decode. Here I only take French file as an example and its code page is 1252. Sadly, every time if there is a double quotes, when I print the string in Python shell, there will be two double quotes unexpectedly.

*The line in .rc source file:*

La fonction "Test de télécopie" vérifie.

*The output string in Python shell:*

La fonction ""Test de télécopie"" vérifie.

*Some activities I did:*

```
f = open(filename,"r")         #Used to open .rc source file
for strline in f.readlines():  #Used to read file line by line
    print strline                #Used to print in Python shell
```

*Additional Info:*

a. The double quotes Hex code in .rc source string is: `&#22;`

b. If I open the .rc source file with web browser, it also displays two double quotes unexpectedly.

c. The .rc source file is confidential, so I didn't attach here.

d. OS: Enu Win7 x64\Python: v2.7

I'm a newbie for Python. Any ideas will be really really appreciated.

Best Regards,
;)

Comment: try `print repr(strline)` and tell us what it says.

Comment: Re-thg435: I tried print repr(strline), but nothing changed. It still displays two double quotes.

Comment: Could you copy and paste here what `print repr(strline)` displays?

Comment: Re-thg435: Here it is: La fonction ""Test de t\xe9l\xe9copie"" v\xe9rifie

Comment: have you tried viewing the source file with [hexdump](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/hextools.htm) or similar utility?

Comment: @thg435: I have tried to use XVI32(http://www.chmaas.handshake.de/delphi/freeware/xvi32/xvi32.htm) to view the hex code (22). I believe the hexdump tool you referred is similar to this one, is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the misunderstanding comes from that I'm not familiar with .rc files (I never used C++ before) and how does the developer handle the strings. Don't punch me if my answer looks so untutored. :)

After talking with the relevant developers, it's confirmed to be a mechanism added by the .rc file creators which is used to handle the double quotes in strings.

Like a string below:
GUI expects-How are you, "Mark"?

In .rc(or web browser)-"How are you, ""Mark"""?

The .rc file creators add this mechanism of adding one more double quotes to surround the original ones in strings, to ensure once the string is called to display in GUI, it will not be recognized as:
-"How are you,"Mark"?" ==>"How are you,"         Mark        "?"==>This would be a messy double quotes match which the GUI can not display correctly.

So I added a filter to remove this additional double quotes in order to get what I want. And I believe it's easy for the Python users.

It's not a professional answer, but I just hope to let the people who encountered same problem think from a different way.

I really appreciate to everybody that helped me identify the problem above before.

Answer (score 0):

Your console are using another code page other than 1252.

**EDIT:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

str=u"""La fonction "Test de télécopie" vérifie."""
print str
flat=str.encode("cp1252")
convts=unicode(flat, encoding="cp850") #Change the testing code page here.
print convts
```

Comment: :The OS is ENU Win7x64. I also checked the "IDLE Preferences-General tab", the "Defualt Source Encoding" is "None". I'm not sure if you referenced to this. Will you please help explain it further?

Comment: @Mark, I am sorry that my guessing may not right, since I have made some tests of several codepages. Now i prefer thg435's method (hexdump the file). According to http://www.science.co.il/language/Character-Code.asp?s=1252, there are 3 Hex (5, 14, 15) correspond to quote. The Editor/Viewer may not support all of them, but your cosole support all of them.

Comment: Actually I have tried a similar tool XVI32 [link] http://www.chmaas.handshake.de/delphi/freeware/xvi32/xvi32.htm to view the hex code and got 22. I did copy and past the source string from .rc file to hexdump using what thg345 referred, and got the same 22 for double quote.

Comment: in .rc source file, it's exactly 22 (not 22 22). In Python shell, the print out string, the hex code is 22 22.

Comment: @Mark, before 22 is what ? in HEX 84, 93, 94? (I make a wrong value at previous comment) They are all for double quote.

Comment: Before 22, it's 20 which I believe it's for whitespace. Nothing unusual can be found according to the hex.